# Random parts of map on MC server dissapear/reset

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm furious with what just happened, the (Bukkit) server I'm working on deleted almost half of something I spent hours building. Does anyone have any clue what could have caused this? I logged off and everything was fine, restarted the server, then when I logged back on it was just gone.

Note: Whatever happened didn't just take a chunk out of my beautiful Isengard, it also rewound a spawn area I was working on by several hours. It wasn't cut in half, just a lot of progress lost.

Could this be caused by my internet's DNS acting up and my connection to the server being faulty? I'm constantly having DNS issues...

Plugins

- factions
- essentials
- godpowers
- mcmmo
- trade
- worldedit
- worldguard

[image: angle 1]
[image: angle 2]

Comment: world edit has a reset command doesn't it? or it could be a corrupt chunk save which triggers a regen

Comment: Good thing you were making backups I guess.

Comment: I never used reset and a corrupt chunk? what?

Comment: @ratchetfreak - it seems too localised for a corrupt chunk. The wall around the tower is intact (for example).

Comment: Fortunately, since you have world edit, it won't be difficult to fix. Simply select the intact half, copy it, rotate the copy 180 degrees, and paste it on the other side.

Comment: @SaintWacko I did, i fixed that but many other places still got screwed over in a non reversible way

Comment: have you considered that you might have griefer issues?

Comment: @ratchetfreak The servers not open to the public yet, I'm the only one who has been on it. And I can assure you I didn't grief myself.

Comment: When you say you "restarted" the server, what did you do? Did you issue a stop command to the Minecraft server, or did you just reboot the operating system?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I logged off and closed the command prompt that was running the server. After that I double clicked on the server and let it load up, when I logged in I noticed stuff was missing

Comment: Closing the command prompt terminates anything running, but doesn't guarantee that there's enough time for the program to do any of its shutdown procedures. It sounds like you may have killed the server before it had the chance to save to disk.

Comment: the way to properly stop a server is by typing "stop" (without the quotes) in the console.

Comment: @Arperum Or, type `/stop` in the chat.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10390), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10568), [What exactly is technical support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/11015) and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft" in the help-center](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13542), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. Outside of those, modded issues are on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a Craftbukkit/Minecraft server suddenly crashes/loses power, it will attempt to save all currently loaded chunks, if one of these chunks is inproperlly saved then it will `Regenerate` that chunk based off the world's `Seed`.

You can prevent this from happening again by `updating/removing` all outdated plugins, correctly shutting down the server in the future and if this issue is that big of a problem, providing the server with a `auxilary power supply` giving it enough time to correcly shut down if such event should happen again.

Comment: Also it can be mitigated by running an auto-save plugin, and taking regular backups.